# Properly Converting Blob to JSON

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I am attempting to retrieve a json file from my drive and read the raw json, like so:

```
function read() {
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById('*********************************').getBlob();
  var data = JSON.parse(blob.getDataAsString());
};
```

I removed the actual file id for obvious reasons, though I have tested and verified that that part retrieves the correct file. The following code gives me this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token in object literal (line 21, file "Code")

The contents of my specified json is simply: {testing123: 'hello world!'}, and is an application/json type file. My goal is to be able to index testing123. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For example, how about modifying from ``{testing123: 'hello world!'}`` to ``{"testing123": "hello world!"}``?

Comment: Can you paste the content of the file?

Comment: @Tanaike Adding quotation marks worked! I still am wondering though why including apostrophe is invalid.

Comment: @Jacob Christianson If this is useful for you, I'm glad. http://www.json.org/